# Spring Eclipse Plugin update site

Tags: eclipse, spring, plugins

Can anyone point me to spring-eclipse plug-in update location so I can use spring from my Eclipse IDE?

None of the ones I found online are working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring works fine without any special eclipse plugins.  Spring have there own version of eclipse called STS ([SpringSource Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/products/sts)) and you could use that.  The [installation instructions (pdf)](http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/doc/STS-installation_instructions.pdf) for STS include instructions for installing the STS components into an existing Eclipse 3.5 installation.

Comment: I already have eclipse...don't want to install some other tool for this..i have done this in the past but could not locate appropriate update location.

Comment: @HonorGod the installation instructions include instruction for installing the STS components into an existing eclipse installation.